# How to change Button Text depending on state of selected tab

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I have the following html snippet used in Angular JS app

```
    <div class="portlet-title tabbable-line">
        <button class="btn btn-sm  green pull-left" ng-click="buildApp(platform)"> {{ getText(platform) }} </button> 
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs ">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#" data-target="#tab_1_1" data-toggle="tab">iOS</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                 <a href="#" data-target="#tab_1_2" data-toggle="tab">Android</a>
            </li>

        </ul>          
    </div>
```

I am trying to work out how to set the Button text depending on which tab is selected. Initially the iOS tab is selected so the button should say 'Build iOS App'. If the Android tab is selected then the button will say 'Build Android App'. I need to set the platform variable depending on the state of the tab, it should be simple but I'm not sure whether I can do this with angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to call function on change of tabs so you can do it like

```
<div class="portlet-title tabbable-line">
            <button class="btn btn-sm  green pull-left" ng-click="buildApp(platform)"> {{ btnName }} </button> 
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs ">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#" data-target="#tab_1_1" data-toggle="tab" ng-click="btn('iOS')">iOS</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                     <a href="#" data-target="#tab_1_2" data-toggle="tab" ng-click="btn('Android')">Android</a>
                </li>
            </ul>          
        </div>
```

in controller

```
 $scope.btnName = 'iOS';
$scope.btn = function (name) {
    $scope.btnName = name;
}
```

Comment: Or you can use jquery to get active list tab value